# pop() method of set class

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

According to Python documentation the `pop()` method removes and returns an **arbitrary element** from the set.

In my example, I have two sets `myset1` and `myset2`. Now when I call `pop()` method on both `myset1` and `myset2`,  `pop()` method always removes and returns the first element of  both sets.  So why does the documetation say:  `pop()` method removes and returns an **arbitrary element** from the set? Because in my example the `pop()` method always removes and returns the first /same element of sets.

```
myset1={i for i in range(99)}
myset2={i for i in range(99)}

for  i in range(99):
  myset1.pop()
  print(myset1)
  myset2.pop()
  print(myset2)
```

Comment: How do you know it is the first? A set is unordered by nature!

Comment: @schwobaseggl Good question, you are right. But my result is always same.